# TestNG xml File Execution

Tags: java, xml, webdriver, testng

Please find my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="RegressionSuite">
<parameter name="selenium.host" value="localhost" />
<parameter name="selenium.port" value="3737" />
<parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*firefox" />
<parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress/" />
    <test name="Max IM Reviewer Test case Execution" preserve-order="true"
    enabled="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="webdriver.Testcase1">
            <methods>
                <include name="savedAction" />
                <include name="submitAction" />                             
            </methods>
        </class>            
        <class name ="webdriver.Testcase2">
        <methods>
        <include name ="role_verification" />
        <include name ="do_loginverify" />
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

have a two class file (Testcase1, Testcase2), my aim is to execute all the Methods one by one in the above class, so i will add those classes and methods in xml file and execute it

while executing the above "Two Web driver instance are created (i.e two browsers - IE) simultaneously, but its executed any one class file (Testcase1) , at the same time another instance was in idle state, so please help me

how to execute all the class one by one
Is it Required any modification the above xml?

Thanks
prabu

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....seperate the TestCase classes into two  for each class.

```
<test>
<classes>
<class>
</class>
</classes>

<test>
<test>
<classes>
<class>
</class>
</classes>
<test>
```

Comment: While there are different ways to achieve your req, think about other points when deciding the xml design like - if you dont want run any test then do you go to the code and remove @test/group tag or change accordingly in xml....

Answer (score 0):

```
1. no need to enter every test into the xml

        <suite name="Alma" verbose="10" parallel="false">
        <test name="Full Regression">
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="priority1" />
                </run>
            </groups>
            <packages>
                <package name="com.mycompany.qa.automation.alma.tests" />
            </packages>        
        </test>
    </suite>

2.for every test please add 

    @Test(groups = { "priority1" })
        public void myTest(){
    }

3 run by the group more ease to run no need to change the xml
```